# background color not covering entire page

Tags: html, css

I want the purple background color to cover the entire page, but the background color cuts off before the image. How do you solve this?

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="section about">
        <div class = "title"> Our Team </div>
        <p class = "description"> The iGEM Team is comprised of 32 ppl. </p>

        <img class="aboutImage" src="images/teamPhoto.jpg" alt="Team Photo" width = "600" />
  </div>
```

**CSS (updated code)**

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.section {
  background-image: linear-gradient(137deg, #D0BAFF 0%, #AD8BF6 27%, #AA88FE 52%, #B77BF6 73%, #D7AAEB 100%);
 }

.about {
   padding-top: 7%;
   position: relative;

}

 .about .description {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.about .title {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.aboutImage {
    position: absolute; /*absolute means object will be relative to the next parent element with relative (or absolute) positioning.*/
}
```

Comment: add `height: 100%;` to `html,body`

Comment: is a solution to set `min-height: 100vh;` to `.section`?

Answer (score 2):

html and body need to be full height for the relative height to work

```
html, body {
  height: 100%
}
```

you can add a clearfix to section to force it to be the height of it's children

```
.section:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
    }
* html .section             { zoom: 1; } /* IE6 */
*:first-child+html .section { zoom: 1; } /* IE7 */
```

Comment: hmm i did that but there is still some white space. when I add `height: 120%` to `.about`, the purple background covers the entire page. I don't want to manually changing the height of `.about` every time. Is there a way around this?

Comment: you shouldn't have to... can you post the full html or a picture of the updated problem

Comment: I copied and pasted your solution but it didn't work. When I make my window size smaller, I get the image I posted above. I updated my code above.

Answer (score 0):

Just make body scrollable with 100% height (and put background in it, not section):

http://codepen.io/themeler/pen/JEBWWb

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
   background-image: linear-gradient(137deg, #D0BAFF 0%, #AD8BF6 27%, #AA88FE 52%, #B77BF6 73%, #D7AAEB 100%);
}

.about {
   padding-top: 7%;
   position: relative;
}

 .about .description {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.about .title {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.aboutImage {
    position: absolute; /*absolute means object will be relative to the next parent element with relative (or absolute) positioning.*/
}
```